# How to open up an old screen session after ssh logged out

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I am getting the following message:

`$ screen -R Poly
There are several suitable screens on:
    14583.PolygenicOCD3 (Detached)
    61499.Poly  (Detached)
    13205.PolygenicOCD  (Detached)
    62250.PolygenicOCD3 (Detached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.`

How do I open the 61499.Poly screen? I tried typing screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host but got nothing. What's the right command?

Comment: `screen -r 61499`

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question: 
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.

screen -r [pid.]tty.host to resume on of them.

As he said->

screen -r 61499 – MariusMatutiae